# How to assign a value in dropdownlist by knockout databind

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

I need to assign a value to DropDownlist by knockout databind.
Below is the ajax request

```
$.ajax({
                       url: "getProducts.json",
                       //GET method is used
                       type: "post",
                       //pass the data
                       data: data,
                       dataType: 'json',
                       success : function(response) {
                           function inventoryProductRowsModel(inventoryProductRowsData, storeData) {
                            var self= this;
                            this.inventoryProductRowsData = inventoryProductRowsData;
                            this.storeData = storeData;
                           // var selectedStores = ko.observable();
                        }
                        var  inventoryProductRowsData = response.inventoryProductRows;
                        ko.applyBindings(inventoryProductRowsModel(inventoryProductRowsData,storeObject.storeRows), document.getElementById("inventoryProductId"));
                       }
});
```

Below is the way i handle dropdown

```
<select data-bind="options: storeData,optionsText: 'storeName',optionsValue: 'id'" id ="sellerStoreIdSizes" name="storeId" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of your viewmodel like this:

```
ko.applyBindings(new inventoryProductRowsModel(inventoryProductRowsData,storeObject.storeRows), document.getElementById("inventoryProductId"));
```